# Are access tokens made redundant by refresh tokens?

Tags: javascript, express, authentication, access-token, refresh-token

I'm new to webdev and have implemented access token & refresh token based authentication in my express project. However, the more I look over the implementation I'm starting to question why access tokens exist when it appears that refresh tokens make them redundant. Perhaps it's just my implementation.

For any task that needs authentication, I send off a cookie with both an access token and refresh token to an auth server. It looks at the access token, and if it is both valid and unexpired, it will send a 200 back and allow any express middleware to continue on.
However if it has expired, it will then query a database to see if a matching refresh token exists and, if so, will send a new access token.

**As the lifetime of the access token decreases, the auth server will need to do more database searches to verify the refresh token. At that rate, why bother with the access token and instead why not rely solely on the refresh token?** After all, the refresh token can be removed from the database and the authorisation server can reject any requests made with it.

The only reason I can think of the access tokens existing is to reduce how often a page will need to query a database, but that seems too simple. Since I'm fairly new to this, I know I must be missing some larger concept. Can anyone enlighten me?

Comment: It sounds like OAuth to me. You can read more about it and see if it gives you the explanation you need.

Comment: Read this, https://hasura.io/blog/best-practices-of-using-jwt-with-graphql/